# return innerhtml of a p class when a button class is clicked custom javascript google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a custom javascript in Google Tag Manager to return the p class text element whenever a specific button is clicked within the div. But my script keeps returning the same initial value.

In GTM, I set the trigger element click based on class "myButton".
and for the variable, I have this custom javascript code.

```
function ()

  {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test-here")[0].innerHTML;
 
    return x;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "mydivd1" class = "test">
<p class = "test-here">   I want to return this text 1</p>
<button class = "mybutton"></button>
</div>


<div id = "mydiv2" class = "test">
<p class = "test-here">   I want to return this text 2</p>
<button class = "mybutton"></button>
</div>
```

How do I return the correct p text element based on the current button class clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using document in the function, use the relative context of the button.

```
function (e)

  {
   var x = e.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("test-here")[0].innerHTML;
 
    return x;
  }
```